# htaccess rule to show my website under a specific path when accessing root domain URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my website inside the following path on my remote web hosting server:

`~/public_html/website/app`

and need to find a way to show it when typing:

`mydomain.com`

so without the need of typing the full path:

`mydomain.com/website/app/`

One solution that came to my mind was to create a `index.php` file inside my root folder to automatically redirect to `./website/app/`:

```
<?php

header('Location: ./website/app/');
exit;
```

but then I need to rewrite the URL in order to go from:

`mydomain.com/website/app/`

to:

`mydomain.com`

and I did not find a way to do that!

So, what do you think I should do to obtain that result and show my website under `/website/app/` when accessing:

`mydomain.com`

and do not show the `/website/app/` folder names?

Thanks a lot!

**edit**:

I was forgetting that I also have the `website/server` path so I need a rule that keeps valid the requests containing `mydomain.com/website/server/`.

Plus, I cannot use:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

on my hosting (for security reasons), it's overridden by:

`Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that.

If you just want to show the  `/website/app` directory for your root url `/` then you can use `DirectoryIndex` directive .

```
DirectoryIndex website/app
```

This will show you the index file from `/website/app`  folder if you visit the your root URI ie : `example.com/` .

If you want to server files and directories from the `/website/app`  instead of the `/` folder then you can use a `RewriteRule` that rewrites your root level requests to the subfolders .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !website/app /website/app℅{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```